# Save to share rabbitmq user across applications?

Tags: rabbitmq

I have a project which consists of a RabbitMQ instance along with several independent components providing various services, all of which will be making use of RabbitMQ for event broadcasting.

My question is whether or not, at the connection level, it's safe to use a single RabbitMQ user for every component. In other words, one RabbitMQ user for the logical "application". Or would it be better to create separate RabbitMQ users for each connection? Would doing so (or not doing so) cause/resolve any concurrency issues or other hiccups? Or would it not matter?

Apologies if this seems obvious, I'm new to RabbitMQ and would rather design things properly up front than deal with unfamiliar headaches later down the road.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be fine to use the same user for each connection. RabbitMQ can handle massive amounts of connections without choking up and the user it is using should not matter. I have worked on applications that have over 100k connections and all using the same user without issues.

Comment: Great, thanks! I just wasn't sure if the rabbitmq user was utilized for anything other than authentication/authorization within the broker. Good to know it's safe to share